# Problems with gethostbyname c++

Tags: c++, windows, gethostbyname

I've this code made in c++ to connect to a server but every time I try "gethostbyname" the value is null(or optimized away and not available).

```
WSADATA wsaData;
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
    cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
hostent *host = gethostbyname("www.example.com");
```

I've tried hostent as volatile but still gives null.
Is there any other way to make this work?
I've tried too Optimization disabled but keeps giving null.

Comment: "Return value

If no error occurs, gethostbyname returns a pointer to the hostent structure described above. Otherwise, it returns a null pointer and a specific error number can be retrieved by calling WSAGetLastError." (MSDN)

Comment: What is the assumed relationship between the opened socket and the host query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`host` is null on error. Check the return value of `WSAGetLastError()` to figure out whats wrong.

Try calling `ping www.example.com` in a cmd shell to check whether the target is reachable from your machine.

To not optimize add:

```
if(host!=NULL && host->h_name)
    cout << "host: " << host->h_name << std::endl;
```

Don't store pointers returned by `gethostbyname()`. They are overridden on the next call by the same thread.

Comment: `gethostbyname()` fails if it cannot resolve the hostname to an IP address, such as via DNS. `ping` is not the same thing as `gethosbyname()`.  `ping` actually checks if the target is reachable on the network, so even if `gethosbyname()` succeeds, `ping` can still fail if there is no network route to the target.

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau 
I did not claim that it's the same, but if ping fails, gethostbyname will likely also fail.

Comment: that depends on how `ping` fails. `ping` may be able to resolve the host name into an IP but still not be able to actually communicate with the host machine.